# Invert serialisation with pyarrow and bytes

Tags: python, string, serialization, deserialization, pyarrow

I have a code that converts dataframe into a string. I can't figure out how to deserialize it back.

```
import pyarrow as pa
context = pa.default_serialization_context()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,8]]), columns=['a','b','c'])

x = gzip.compress(context.serialize(df).to_buffer().hex())
```

So I need a command to get `df` back from `x`.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, but just a note that the `(de)serialize` functions are deprecated (and will be removed in a future version): see https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html#arbitrary-object-serialization for more details

Comment: Yes, i know, but our developer used it.

Answer (score 0):

```
context.deserialize(bytes.fromhex(gzip.decompress(x).decode()))
```